# Selection problem in tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I am making an application where i need tabs placed at the bottom of the screen .
I have managed to get to implement the code of tabs but i can't get them to be placed in the bottom of the screen.

Also i don't want any of the tabs to be selected i.e. i just want four tabs to be present at the bottom of the screen and above the tabs there are some image views and buttons.

I have linked the tabs to respective activites but i don't want the tab bar to be functional until the user wants to go and click it.

Till then i just want a normal gui screen with tabs at the bottom with none of them pre selected.

```
package com.tabs;

import android.app.TabActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables    
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost   
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab   
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab    
    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused) 
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);  
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost   
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey)).setContent(intent);  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);   
    // Do the same for the other tabs   
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class); 
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);  
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class); 
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey)).setContent(intent); 
    tabHost.addTab(spec); 
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here the custom tab [Demo](http://code.google.com/p/androidtabs/)

Comment: Please Format your question properly

Answer (score 0):

---------- To place tab at the bottom add the below code

---

```
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff"><RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"><FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:background="@drawable/bg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"/><TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:background="@drawable/tab_bar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:cacheColorHint="#fff" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:textStyle="bold"/></RelativeLayout></TabHost>
```

##

and if yu dont want any tabs to be selected remove
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);